# Order relationship in RESTful

Tags: 7, services

I'm using https://www.drupal.org/project/restful module. I can sort base entity using annotation:

```
/**
 * Class Things__1_0
 * @package Drupal\restful_thing\Plugin\resource\node\thing
 *
 * @Resource(
 *   name = "things:1.0",
 *   resource = "things",
 *   label = "things",
 *   description = "Export the things with all authentication providers.",
 *   authenticationTypes = TRUE,
 *   authenticationOptional = TRUE,
 *   dataProvider = {
 *     "entityType": "node",
 *     "bundles": {
 *       "course"
 *     },
 *     "sort" = {
 *       "field_weight": "ASC"
 *     },
 *   },
 *   majorVersion = 1,
 *   minorVersion = 0
 * )
 */
```

But when it comes to relationship, the related data isn't ordered the way I need.

Inside `public_fields()`:

```
$public_fields['modules'] = array(
  'property' => 'field_modules',
  'resource' => array(
    'name' => 'modules',
    'fullView' => TRUE,
    'majorVersion' => 1,
    'minorVersion' => 0,
    'dataProvider' => array( //here I'm trying to override dataProvider values
      'sort' => array(
        'field_weight' => 'ASC'
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Is there any way to sort related data?

---edit---

I've also placed "sort" inside the annotation of the modules plugin, but It doesn't have effect too.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the sorting problem with sorting data inside the formatter. Here's my code in case someone had similar problems.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\restful\Plugin\formatter\OrderFormatter.
 */

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\formatter;

use Drupal\restful\Plugin\formatter\FormatterJson;
use Drupal\restful\Plugin\formatter\FormatterInterface;

/**
 * Class OrderFormatter
 * @package Drupal\restful\Plugin\formatter
 *
 * @Formatter(
 *   id = "order_formatter",
 *   label = "ORDER FORMATTER",
 *   description = "Output filtered data",
 *   curie = {
 *     "name": "dis",
 *     "path": "doc/rels",
 *     "template": "/{rel}",
 *   },
 * )
 */
class OrderFormatter extends FormatterJson implements FormatterInterface {

  /**
   * Content Type
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $contentType = 'application/json+sort; charset=utf-8';

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render(array $structured_data) {
    $i=0;
    foreach ($structured_data['data'] as $v) {

      $structured_data['data'][$i]['unsortedThings'] = $this->sortBy($structured_data['data'][$i]['unsortedThings']);
      $i++;
    }
    return drupal_json_encode($structured_data);
  }

  public function sortBy($arr) {
    $results = [];
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
      $results[$k] = $v['weight']; //this is my sorting field
    }
    asort($results, SORT_REGULAR);

    foreach (array_keys($results) as $key) {
      $results[$key] = $arr[$key];
    }
    $results = array_values($results);
    return $results;
  }

}
```

You run this formatter by adding header to your request: `Accept: application/json+sort; charset=utf-8`